# YouTube API Returns Wrong SubscriberCount

Tags: youtube-api

I have two channels examples:

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w => real sub 150k

https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC-2Zibu3OGJdIisYaODXhbQ => real sub 208k

This is what was returned from the Channels list endpoint:

```json
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "wVkhi3RvF1ayB9ou0W6KZcanGZE",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 2,
    "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "QI30osPYB_sy-uwNipgDhEPKRso",
      "id": "UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "17359612",
        "subscriberCount": "320",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "26"
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#channel",
      "etag": "IjATUKKNgPUxmtHQWicg_r22hqc",
      "id": "UC-2Zibu3OGJdIisYaODXhbQ",
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "1723670",
        "subscriberCount": "18",
        "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
        "videoCount": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When you go to the links above, and navigate through the channel, I noticed that the channel Id changes and the API returns the correct sub count for the new Id.

I am unsure how a unique video Id can be linked to more than one channel, What kind of channels are these? merged, linked, or something else? and how does the user do this?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure I understand what your question is. The channels in question have subscribed to private.  If i check those channels on YouTube I cant see the subscriber count.    If i make the same request against my own channel the correct subscriber count is shown.

Comment: Did you do Channels List (part = statistics) and got different results??

Comment: No For my channel using statistics I get the correct subscriber count.  However with the channels you have shown they subscriber count is private so i cant see what the subscriber count is.  I would suggest setting the subscriber count to public if you want to be able to see it in the api.   Private is Private even via the api.

Comment: These are not my channels, and their sub count is set to public as seen in the API "privacyStatus": "public"

Comment: Check the page on YouTube.  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w  <-- do you see a subscriber count.  No that's because its set to private.  How do you know the real sub is 150k if its not your channel.

Comment: Ok, I am sorry that I wasn't clear, click on the same link you gave me, then click on the first video, you will see the channel and its sub count, click on it, and you will end up with the exact link  youtube.com/channel/UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w  and inside it has the sub count public with the same channel id in the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

"click on the same link you gave me, then click on the first video" [there isn't any video on my side](https://i.ibb.co/qBDMX3S/Screenshot-from-2022-08-19-13-16-05.png). Using [PlaylistItems: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/playlistItems/list) with the channel `uploads` playlist I get 26 videos and the first one is [`hVyJsXCXyuo`](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVyJsXCXyuo). Even if all retrieved videos are unavailable, for the first video I indeed see that the channel real subscribers count is 150k and if I click on the channel name I get redirected to another channel that is [`UC4LyPYXnF07KF97Nb8vE_Pg`](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC4LyPYXnF07KF97Nb8vE_Pg) which indeed has 150k subscribers.

Then you can use [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) to get the correct subscriber count using `id=UC4LyPYXnF07KF97Nb8vE_Pg` cf https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=UC4LyPYXnF07KF97Nb8vE_Pg&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Note that under a video the channel id you are redirected to seems to differ if you click on the channel avatar or the channel name on a desktop. The following redirection are done if you are on a phone or a computer and if you click on the channel avatar or channel name:

Phone:

- Name: `UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w`
- Avatar: `UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w`

Computer:

- Name: `UC4LyPYXnF07KF97Nb8vE_Pg`
- Avatar: `UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w`

Comment: The channel link subscriber is [not shown](https://ibb.co/s12WDkr) When you click on this video [hVyJsXCXyuo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hVyJsXCXyuo) then click on the channel name, you will be redirected to the same channel [Id](https://ibb.co/tqzPtKB) , both have an identical address and channel id.

Comment: Have you correctly clicked on the channel name and not the channel avatar ? As it redirects to different channel ids cf [the edit of my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73414827/revisions).

Comment: My question is these 2 channels related somehow? and can a video share 2 channels in youtube API?

Comment: It seems that YouTube Data API v3 doesn't support such thing. Are you looking for an API that gives you the original channel id (here `UC4LyPYXnF07KF97Nb8vE_Pg`) from the "topic" channel id (here`UC56eaiucsjSfKgevcaGcn2w`) ? If so, webscraping is the solution and it fits the scope of [my open-source YouTube operational API](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API).